# multiple d3 graphs in a single page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Actually i am showing a d3 graph in a browser. Now the change is to show dynamic number of d3 graphs on a single browser. So i tried to create two more svg elements inside my previous div tag. But it is not working. But some of the samples which i referred shows the same thing.

```
 <div id="container">
                <svg id="svgcontainer"></svg>
                <svg id="svgcontainer1"></svg>
                <svg id="svgcontainer2"></svg>
            </div>



   var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer").attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);
            var svg1 = d3.select("#svgcontainer1").attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);
            var svg2 = d3.select("#svgcontainer2").attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);


            svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
           .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
         .enter().append("marker")
           .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
           .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
           .attr("refX", 12)
           .attr("refY", 0)
           .attr("markerWidth", 6)
           .attr("markerHeight", 6)
           .attr("orient", "auto")
         .append("path")
           .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
           .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
           .style("opacity", "1");

            svg1.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
          .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("marker")
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          .attr("refX", 12)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 6)
          .attr("markerHeight", 6)
          .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
          .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
          .style("opacity", "1");

            svg2.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
          .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("marker")
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          .attr("refX", 12)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 6)
          .attr("markerHeight", 6)
          .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
          .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
          .style("opacity", "1");
```

But it is not working.

I am adding the whole code here.

```
  <div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
            <div id="container">
                <svg id="svgcontainer"></svg>

                <svg id="svgcontainer1"></svg>

                <svg id="svgcontainer2"></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <%--to add tooltip for node--%>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>
        <script>


            var selectednode;
            console.log(document.getElementById("hdnLink").value);
            var graph = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hdnLink").value);

            // for TFL graph
            var width = 4000,
                height = 4000;

            //var width = 3000,
            //    height = 3000;
            debugger;

            var color = d3.scale.category20();





            var force = d3.layout.force()
            //.charge(-3000)
                .charge(function (d) { return d.degree * -250; })
            .chargeDistance(500)
            .linkDistance(5)
            .size([width, height]);

            //var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
            //    .attr("width", width)
            //    .attr("height", height);

            var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer").attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);
            var svg1 = d3.select("#svgcontainer1").attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);
            var svg2 = d3.select("#svgcontainer2").attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);


            svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
           .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
         .enter().append("marker")
           .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
           .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
           .attr("refX", 12)
           .attr("refY", 0)
           .attr("markerWidth", 6)
           .attr("markerHeight", 6)
           .attr("orient", "auto");

            svg.append("path")
              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
              .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
              .style("opacity", "1");

            svg1.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
          .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("marker")
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          .attr("refX", 12)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 6)
          .attr("markerHeight", 6)
          .attr("orient", "auto");
            svg1.append("path")
              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
              .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
              .style("opacity", "1");

            svg2.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
          .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("marker")
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          .attr("refX", 12)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 6)
          .attr("markerHeight", 6)
          .attr("orient", "auto");

            svg2.append("path")
              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
              .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
              .style("opacity", "1");


            ARROW_SHIFT = 1;
            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
              .enter().append('svg:path')
                //.attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)")
                //.attr("display", "none")
                .attr("display", function (d) {
                    if (document.getElementById("chkShowAnimation").checked == true) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                        return "none";
                })
                .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
               .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)")
                .attr('marker-start', function (d) {
                    return d.birectional ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : null;
                });

            var link1 = svg1.selectAll(".link")
               .data(graph.links)
             .enter().append('svg1:path')
               //.attr("class", "link")
               .style("stroke", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)")
               //.attr("display", "none")
               .attr("display", function (d) {
                   if (document.getElementById("chkShowAnimation").checked == true) {
                       return null;
                   }
                   else
                       return "none";
               })
               .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
              .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)")
               .attr('marker-start', function (d) {
                   return d.birectional ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : null;
               });

            var link2 = svg2.selectAll(".link")
               .data(graph.links)
             .enter().append('svg2:path')
               //.attr("class", "link")
               .style("stroke", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)")
               //.attr("display", "none")
               .attr("display", function (d) {
                   if (document.getElementById("chkShowAnimation").checked == true) {
                       return null;
                   }
                   else
                       return "none";
               })
               .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
              .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)")
               .attr('marker-start', function (d) {
                   return d.birectional ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : null;
               });

            var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function (d) {
    return d.name + " , " + d.group;
})
            svg.call(tip);
            svg1.call(tip);
            svg2.call(tip);
```

> The Input for this sample is

{"nodes" : [{"name":"NithyaShree","group":"Family1","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310477"},{"name":"SowmyaShree","group":"Family1","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310478"},{"name":"Lakshmanan","group":"Family1","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310479"},{"name":"Rajeshwari","group":"Family1","degree":6,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310480"},{"name":"Ravi","group":"Family2","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310481"},{"name":"Komi","group":"Family2","degree":5,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310482"},{"name":"Pooja","group":"Family2","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310483"},{"name":"Harish","group":"Family3","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310484"},{"name":"Girish","group":"Family3","degree":5,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310485"},{"name":"Laxman","group":"Family3","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310486"},{"name":"Kirthi","group":"Family4","degree":5,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310487"},{"name":"Saran","group":"Family4","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310488"},{"name":"Selvaraj","group":"Family4","degree":2,"Opacity":"1","highlight":"false","clicked":"false","colorname":"#FFFFFF","optionid":"310489"}], "links" : [{"source":0,"target":3,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":1,"target":3,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":2,"target":3,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":3,"target":3,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.500000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":4,"target":5,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":5,"target":5,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.400000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":6,"target":5,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":7,"target":8,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":8,"target":8,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.400000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":9,"target":8,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":10,"target":10,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.400000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":11,"target":10,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"},{"source":12,"target":10,"Opacity":"1","strength":"0.100000","bidirectional":"False","highlight":"false"}] }

Comment: is there any error in console ? Also what do you want to draw ? http://jsbin.com/pepijutina/edit?html,js,output I cant see any output it just shows blank.

Comment: You are not seeing anything coz you are just making markers inside the defs.

Comment: @murli2308 No errors in console. I added the whole code there. Please check

Comment: @Cyril. Ok.. But i am confused to proceed where i can change since i am completely new to d3. Help me to get thr'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've mis-understood slightly how `D3` is working with it's method chaining. The following for example will create an `<a>` tag in a `<p>` in a `<div>`:

```
d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "test")
  .append("p")
  .append("a");
```

What you're doing is creating the following DOM:

```
<svg>
   <defs>
      <marker>
         <path/>
      </marker>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

The problem is that it doesn't make sense for a `<path>` to sit within a `<defs>`. Instead you want to re-select your `<svg>` and add it like so (note that your code doesn't actually render much to screen, just 3 small lines):

```js
var width = 300;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var svg1 = d3.select("#svgcontainer1").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var svg2 = d3.select("#svgcontainer2").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 12)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto");

svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
    .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
    .style("opacity", "1");

svg1.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 12)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto");

svg1.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
    .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
    .style("opacity", "1");

svg2.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 12)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto");

svg2.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
    .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
    .style("opacity", "1");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="svgcontainer"></svg>
  <svg id="svgcontainer1"></svg>
  <svg id="svgcontainer2"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: No @lan.. It is not working.. i tried as you suggested. Still i cant

Comment: @NithyaShree : Well can you provide a full snippet we can execute to demonstrate your problem? Because the original question you posted this resolved. If you need to clarify your question that's fine - but it'd be nice if you could give us something to actually execute.